# How to cache results of requests in Tomcat 7?

Tags: tomcat, tomcat7, jax-rs, cdi

I have some routes in my web application that I want cache its results.

Example: `domain.com/client/1`

This route make some queries in my database resulting in an JSON with 1~2mb. I want cache the result of this route. But I want too expires it in one minute. How the best way to make this?

Comment: Set a http cache header for 60 seconds. Or create a serverside cache that caches for all clients.

Comment: Do you want a server side cache?

Answer (score 2):

For a server side cache, you could have a look at [JCACHE](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=107) ([JSR 107](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=107)).

Cache solutions such as [Ehcache](http://www.ehcache.org/) and [Infinispan](http://infinispan.org/) implement the [JSR 107](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=107).

### Infinispan

With Infinispan, for example, you can set a life span for your cache entries:

```java
Configuration configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                                      .expiration()
                                      .lifespan(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                      .build();

Cache<Object, Object> cache = new DefaultCacheManager(configuration).getCache();
cache.put("key", "value");
cache.remove("key");
```

To use Infinispan, just add the following dependency your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.infinispan</groupId>
    <artifactId>infinispan-embedded</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

If you are not using Maven, download it from the [Infinispan download page](http://infinispan.org/download/).

### Guava

You also could have a look at the [cache API provided by Guava](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/CachesExplained):

```java
Cache<Object, Object> cache = CacheBuilder.newBuilder()
                                  .expireAfterWrite(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                                  .build();

cache.put("key", "value");
cache.invalidate("key");
```

To use it, add the following dependency to your `pom.xml`:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>18.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: lol the infinispan-minimal zip from their site is 26MB! I would use `caffeine` or `guava cache` if my project was using guava. Also if the OP is going to cache a lot of such huge objects in the heap it will badly hurt GC

Comment: That's a nice observation, but the question is not very specific about the requirements.